# Asking ThinkingSphinx not to search in specific attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

In a model,

I have defined indexes on some columns and have defined some attributes.

On some external application conditions, I don't want to sphinx to search in some columns values.

Answer (score 3):

In the question name, do you mean attributes or fields? I'm guessing fields, as attributes are only used for filters...

So, to search on just specific fields, you can make a query like the following:

```
Model.search "@(title, body, user) foo bar", :match_mode => :extended
```

Put all the fields you want to search on within the parentheses, and you should be good to go.